# Let $X$ be a nonempty set, then a collection $\tau=\{U \subseteq X \mid U=\emptyset \vee U^c \ \text{is finite}\}$ of $X$ is a topology on $X$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a nonempty set. Prove that the collection of subsets $\tau=\{U \subseteq X \mid U=\emptyset \vee U^c \ \text{is finite}\}$ of $X$ is a topology on $X$.

**Attempt:**
First, it's clear that $\emptyset \in \tau$.
Since $X^c=\emptyset$, we have $X \in \tau$.

Second, let $U_1,U_2 \in \tau$. We'll show that $U_1 \cap U_2 \in \tau$.
If $U_1 = \emptyset$ or $U_2 = \emptyset$, then $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset \in \tau$. Assume that both of $U_1$ and $U_2$ are not empty.
Since $U_1,U_2 \in \tau$, we have $U_1^c$ and $U_2^c$ are both finite, by definition of $\tau$. Notice by De Morgan's Law that $(U_1 \cap U_2)^c = U_1^c \cup U_2^c$. Since $U_1^c$ and $U_2^c$ are both finite, $U_1^c \cup U_2^c$ is also finite. Therefore, $(U_1 \cap U_2)^c$ is finite and hence, $U_1 \cap U_2 \in \tau$.

Third, let $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \tau$.
We want to show that $\bigcup \mathcal{U} \in \tau$. Clearly, if $\mathcal{U} \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$, then $\bigcup \mathcal{U} = \emptyset$. So, assume that $\mathcal{U} \notin \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$.
Then, there exists $U_0 \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $U_0 \ne \emptyset$. In other word, $U_0^c$ is finite.
Now, notice that
$$\left(\bigcup \mathcal{U}\right)^c = \left(\bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U\right)^c = \bigcap_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U^c \subseteq U_0^c.$$
Since $U_0^c$ is finite, we have $(\bigcup \mathcal{U})^c$ is finite too.
Hence, $\bigcup \mathcal{U} \in \tau$.

Therefore, $\tau$ is a topology on $X$.

Is this approach correct? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It is very correct :)

Comment: Correct. Trust yourself! By the way, this topology is known as the *cofinite topology*.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. :D